# Typo3 extbase: change record pid programmatically

Tags: typo3, parent, record, move, extbase

I have a NewsRepository and a News model.
The storagePid is 74.
I have a script which checks if the endtime field of the new record is overdue. If it is, I want to move the record in another folder (UID 170).

When I do:

```
$news = $newsRepository->findByUid( 1 );
$news->setTitle( 'News ' . rand(1,99999) );
$news->setPid( 170 );
$newsRepository->update( $news );
```

The title is changed, but the PID is not.

So, how can I move the new onto another page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the pid to the TCA.

This is the correct way, so it wont be displayed in the backend.

```
'pid' => array(
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'passthrough',
    )
),
```

Comment: Hi @user3655829 & @cili, could you point me to a resource or explain a bit why the TCA is needed to use `setPid()`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You will find this in the general TCA definition and documentation. You simple need this because typo3 wont know the table column if you dont config it. There is no magic. TCA == Table Definition Array. So here you config all the fields youo found in the db. Event the pid and uid field.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the **pid** filed should be set in TCA also.
I added

```
'pid' => Array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'PID',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'none',
    )
),
```

in the **columns** section of the TCA and now the PID is saved.